# OTS parsing error: Failed to convert WOFF 2.0 font to SFNT for font files of Glyphicon for Spring-boot

Tags: angularjs, maven, spring-boot, glyphicons

When trying to use Glyphicons with Algular inside a Spring-boot Java project created through maven, icons are not shown, and these following errors can be seen in console:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: <URL> ..
OTS parsing error: Failed to convert WOFF 2.0 font to SFNT
OTS parsing error: incorrect file size in WOFF header
OTS parsing error: incorrect entrySelector for table directory
```

There are some solutions around here, but none of them considers Spring-Boot Maven scenario.

Comment: check this too - a different filtering exclusion configuration - https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/908

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems like Maven build resources somehow corrupts those files and Bootstrap can not decode them anymore properly, resulting in these errors.
One workaround I have found is to add nonFilteredFileExtensions in maven-resources-plugin:

```
<configuration>
    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    <nonFilteredFileExtension>ttf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
    <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff</nonFilteredFileExtension>
    <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff2</nonFilteredFileExtension>
    <nonFilteredFileExtension>eot</nonFilteredFileExtension>
    <nonFilteredFileExtension>svg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
 </configuration>
```

Here, we can add all extensions of font/icon files that maven is corrupting, and it should solve the issue.

Plugin section should have something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>ttf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff2</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>eot</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>svg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It solves the problem, but what actually nonFilteredFileExtensions do to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm trying to use frontend-maven-plugin with reactjs. This solved my problem , thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For angular + aws, add this: 
  'image/svg+xml',
  'font/ttf',
  'font/woff',
  'font/woff2',

to binaryMimeTypes.

Comment: this helped me for an express-based application running on AWS Lambda.

Comment: `const binaryMimeTypes = ['application/octet-stream',' font/eot', 'font/opentype', 'font/otf', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/svg+xml', 'font/ttf', 'font/woff', 'font/woff2']` will be available in lambda.js file

Comment: @BenClayton Could you clarify where you add this specifically?

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal where did you add this?

Comment: @qarthandso we were using serverless-http library in a javascript lamda. In the root javascript file we use: `module.exports.server = serverless(app, {  binary: binaryMimeTypes});`